# Why not notify faculty candidates of the position being filled?

Tags: etiquette, job

There is a certain faculty position (Associate Prof) that has been offered to someone, and got accepted. Is there some reason for which other candidates have not been notified of this?

I find this meaningless and rude, given that the other candidates may make serious career choices, thinking that they are still considered / there is a possibility of them getting this position (eg declining other expiring offers).

To give more context, the interviews for position happened around 2 months ago, and the offer/acceptance was made around a week ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may just be a matter of timing. Such letters to failed candidates wouldn't normally be sent until there was a signed contract with the accepted person. I can't guarantee that it is universal practice to notify failed candidates, but suspect that it is the general practice.

On the other hand, the other applicants would be foolish to turn down other offers without positive assurance of success unless they are willing to risk the consequences. They have been free to ask about their status, of course.

But "acceptance" of an offer also requires certain bureaucratic procedures be completed and they take a bit of time. A week isn't enough in many cases.

Comment: For example, accepting a job offer may trigger additional steps, such as a background check or a drug test (depending on the job). The offer is contingent on the candidate passing those hurdles. So even if 'accepted', the offer may not survive the next steps, and if so the institution would move on to the next candidate.